# Why does Backbone's event obj have missing properties?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I was working on some drag/drop functionality and was attaching events through the standard Backbone way:

```
events: { 
 'dragenter': 'dragEnter',
 'dragend': 'dragEnd'
 ....,
 .....
}
```

I noticed in my function that the `event` object that is passed into it doesn't contain some properties outlined in the html5 spec.

Specifically, the `dataTransfer` obj is missing.

I created a quick demo to [demonstrate my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/QxSVb/1/). Just drag a file or something over it to see it in the logs.

My question is why does this happen? I have looked through the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) and can't seem to find it.

Comment: Try to remove the Backbone layer to see if the issue is in the jQuery its self: `$("#dom-element").bind( "dragenter", function(event){ console.log( "event", event ); } );`

Comment: @fguillen yeah that works, regular js event bindings work as well. I was just curious as to why its happening

Comment: I don't know, Backbone looks like it delegates to the jQuery events binding, [look this code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1237-1254), so Backbone's event system should works as fine as jQuery's events system :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Backbone Events, Backbone puts a layer on top of the actual event.
If you want to access the original event you'll have to use: **event.originalEvent**.

In the originalEvent you'll find dataTransfer.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone events actually bind events to your Dom library (jQuery, Zepto ...) so you should load jqueryui if you want draggable events

Comment: While it is true that it binds the events using those DOM manipulators, simply adding jqUI doesn't fix the problem, at least not in my testing.

Comment: Since dataTransfer is native you could access it through your callback : `dragEnter: function(e) { dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer }` so this is what I meant by binding the events to jQuery

Comment: Ah. Didnt even realize `originalEvent` existed.